# Download by ADM download manager in Android Studio

Tags: android

I looked for a code and did not find it, so I decided to ask a question.
I want to put a download Button in my application and when the user clicks on it, the ADM download manager application will open and the link will be inserted automatically and the download will start. I found the following code, but this code only copies the da link in the clipboard, and the user has to put the da link in the app himself. I want this to be done automatically.

```
                boolean isAppInstalled = appInstalledOrNot("com.dv.adm");

            SharedPreferences prfs = getSharedPreferences("AUTHENTICATION_FILE_NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            String url = prfs.getString("url", "");

            ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
            ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("download link", url);
            clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);

            if (isAppInstalled) {
                //This intent will help you to launch if the package is already installed
                Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager()
                        .getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.dv.adm");
                startActivity(LaunchIntent);
                Toast.makeText(MovieActivity.this, "The download link was copied to your clipboard.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MovieActivity.this, "ADM is not installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

Comment: Put the url in an extra of the intent.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.setPackage("com.dv.adm");
            ComponentName name = new ComponentName("com.dv.adm","com.dv.get.AEditor");
            intent.setComponent(name);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,url);
//Bellow is automated by ADM if you don't set. It is just filename
            intent.putExtra("com.android.extra.filename",your_file+".mp4");
            startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: tnx dear @nayThurein .. it's working for me :)